# Fundamental Theorem Of Linear Maps - Missing Step in proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been studying the proof for the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right, 3rd ed.* and I have been stumbling on a step that seems to be missing a justification near the end of Axler's proof. I've boxed out in red the portion that I am not understanding.

My question is: we know up to the red box that $v_1,...,v_n$ are linearly independent, however how does that lead to the assertion that $Tv_1,...,Tv_n$ are linearly independent? What result am I missing that justifies this step?

[image: Axler's Proof]

Comment: $v_1, \dots, v_n$ aren't *proven* to be linearly independent, they just *are* (see the first sentence of the proof), and it is used to show that the $c_i$s are all zero.

Comment: Right above it says that "to show that $Tv_1,...,Tv_n$ is LI, suppose $c_1,...,c_N \in F$ and .... ". So he is justifying this assertiom

Comment: Please do not rely on images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [See here for an explanation.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I just wasn't reading this properly. *Facepalm*

The proof proposed earlier on to test $Tw_1,...,Tw_n$ for independence by setting up the equation $0 = c_1Tw_1 + ... + c_nTw_n$ and finding out what all the $c_i$ should be. They all should be zero, so the $Tw_i$ are all linearly independent.